# Can we hook the Customizer on a post or page on the front of the site?

Tags: user-roles, theme-customizer

If you go theme shopping on various company sites like https://themeforest.net/, you will notice that within many demos, there is a pull out feature that allows you to change the look and feel of that particular theme page (i.e. dark version / light version).

This inspired me to ask the question if the customizer (or anything similar to it) can be loaded on the front end, on a specific post or page, so that front end users can do similar things like change colors (obviously something I will have to code in), but hopefully you get the idea.  If I wanted to show case several themes I built for a client, I would want them to have the ability to do a "customizer experience" without accessing the dashboard area.

Is this possible? Is it already built? or do I have to rebuild something like this up from scratch? Or can I hook into something to pull out the customizer to the front end? I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad for a Q&A model, but I tend to think that everything you need is already built in. Except that you will want your clients to login, something you can have them do on the front end.

You could even make a [custom role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) which will allow you to hide the whole admin bar from them except for the button that lets them open the theme customizer.

In the theme customizer you can change the [capability on settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference%5CWP_Customize_Manager%5Cadd_setting), which will make some of them available for users with low clearance. In this way you can prevent them accessing settings they have no business with.

You can use the [active callback on sections](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section) to load different sections for different types of pages (front, archive, singular, and so on).

If you don't want them to save their actions, hide the save button.

Comment: That is exactly the creative planning I was hoping for.  Thank you so much!   I'll give these approaches a shot, because yes...I would like to remain native as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

"Without the hassle of logging in" is a little concerning, but I assume you mean "logging in/editing without using the Wordpress dashboard".

There are a few plugins that make things better, but they can still be pretty overwhelming.  Keep in mind, that combining a lot of plugins might not work as smoothly as you'd probably like.

First, I use [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) to literally theme the login/logout/profile/forgot password pages.  It's pretty simple to setup, and it has a few more settings to get into if you read through it a bit.

Secondly, for most of the adding/editing of posts & pages, I've used [Visual Composer](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431?ref=WPExplorer&ref=WPExplorer&clickthrough_id=847873869&redirect_back=true).  The biggest issue with VC is that it can feel really bloated when there are a lot of things going on.  And it is kind of overwhelming, but it gives you a massive amount of tools for changing the structure and layout on the front side.

For things like the actual Theme Customizer?  I'd still recommend using that, because it's built into WordPress and runs natively, it'll provide a decent experience without weighing down your install.  I haven't used anything else for this, but a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=front+end+theme+customizer+wordpress&oq=front+end+theme+customizer+wordpress&aqs=chrome..69i57.5631j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turns up a few.

Anyway, hope that answers your question.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, you are correct - let me re-word my statement about that part of my question.  I really meant, "not accessing the dashboard".